# Combine two different queries

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this query:

```
select 
    CLIENTS.ID,
    CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || CLIENTS.LAST_NAME as PATIENT,
    CLIENTS.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID as PAYMENT_TYPE,
    sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) as PRICE,
    sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as PAID,
    sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as DIF
from 
    SESSIONS SESSIONS,
    CLIENTS CLIENTS 
where 
    SESSIONS.CLIENTS_ID = CLIENTS.ID 
    and SESSIONS.STATUS in (4,5)
having 
    sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) <> 0
group by 
    CLIENTS.ID, CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || CLIENTS.LAST_NAME, CLIENTS.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID
order by 
    sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) desc
```

and the result is:

[image]

I also have this query:

```
SELECT 
    TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - TRUNC(SESSION_DATE) AS total_unpaid_days, 
    TO_CHAR(SESSION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS first_unplaid_date
FROM  
    SESSIONS
WHERE
    CLIENTS_ID = 7
    AND STATUS = 5
    AND PAYMENT_STATUS = 1
ORDER BY 
    SESSIONS.ID ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

but as you can see I have to manually provide the `clients_id`.

Is it possible to combine these two queries and add to my first query two new columns with the results of the second query?

I try to compine like this:

```
    select CLIENTS.ID,
        CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || CLIENTS.LAST_NAME as PATIENT,
        CLIENTS.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID as PAYMENT_TYPE,
 TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - TRUNC(SESSION_DATE) as total_unpaid_days, 
        to_char(SESSION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as first_unplaid_date,
        sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) as PRICE,
        sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as PAID,
        sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as DIF
     from SESSIONS SESSIONS,
        CLIENTS CLIENTS 
     where SESSIONS.CLIENTS_ID=CLIENTS.ID 
     and SESSIONS.STATUS in (4,5)
     having sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) <>0
     group by CLIENTS.ID, CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || CLIENTS.LAST_NAME, CLIENTS.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID, TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - TRUNC(SESSION_DATE), to_char(SESSION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
     order by sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) desc
```

but i am getting the clients without sum....

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi @marc_s and thank you very much for your comment. Oracle APEX 21.1 automatically gave this type of joins. This version was released a month ago..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

```
select p.ID as P_ID,
    p.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || p.LAST_NAME as PATIENT,
    p.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID as PAYMENT_TYPE, tm.First_Unpaid_date, Owes_days, Charge, Paid, Diff
    from CLIENTS p
        inner join SESSIONS s on p.ID = s.CLIENTS_ID
    inner join (
        select CLIENTS_ID,
            max(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - TRUNC(SESSION_DATE)) as Owes_days,
            sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) as Charge,
            sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as Paid,
            sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as Diff,
            min(SESSION_DATE) as First_Unpaid_date
        from SESSIONS
        where PAYMENT_STATUS = 1
        and STATUS in (4,5)
        having sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) <>0
        group by CLIENTS_ID
    ) tm on p.ID = tm.CLIENTS_ID and s.SESSION_DATE = tm.First_Unpaid_date
    and s.PAYMENT_STATUS = 1
    and s.STATUS in (1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
Select CLIENTS.ID,
    CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || CLIENTS.LAST_NAME as PATIENT,
    CLIENTS.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID as PAYMENT_TYPE,
    Sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) as PRICE,
    Sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as PAID,
    Sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - Sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) as DIF,
        
    (SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - TRUNC(SESSION_DATE)      
     FROM  SESSIONS
     Where CLIENTS_ID = CLIENTS.ID AND
           STATUS = 5 AND
           PAYMENT_STATUS = 1 AND
           RowNum = 1
     Order By SESSIONS.ID ASC) AS total_unpaid_days,
     
    (SELECT To_Char(SESSION_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
     FROM  SESSIONS
     Where CLIENTS_ID = CLIENTS.ID AND
           STATUS = 5 AND
           PAYMENT_STATUS = 1 AND
           RowNum = 1
     Order By SESSIONS.ID ASC) AS first_unplaid_date

    
 From SESSIONS SESSIONS
 Join CLIENTS CLIENTS ON SESSIONS.CLIENTS_ID=CLIENTS.ID 
 where SESSIONS.STATUS in (4,5)
 Having Sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - Sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) <> 0
 Group By CLIENTS.ID, CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || CLIENTS.LAST_NAME, CLIENTS.PAYMENT_TYPE_ID
 Order By Sum(SESSIONS.PRICE) - Sum(SESSIONS.AMOUNT) Desc
```

Comment: Hello %MundoPeter and thank you very much for your answer. If i run each of this internal select as standalone, i get a value (i believe it is the correct one), For example the first one:(SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - TRUNC(SESSION_DATE)      
     FROM  SESSIONS, CLIENTS
     Where CLIENTS_ID = CLIENTS.ID AND
           STATUS = 5 AND
           PAYMENT_STATUS = 1 AND
           RowNum = 1
     Order By SESSIONS.ID ASC) AS total_unpaid_days -> gives me: 18. But as a whole query, I get this error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The Internal selects can not be run on its own since they are refering to CLIENTS.ID which is a variable from the outer select. In my answer ther is no problem with right/left parentesis, I think you have modified the sentence introducind that problem. Does my answer not work?

Comment: when i run your whole query (your answer) i get this error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. I don't know why, but it doesn't work.